# Run dotnet tests without excluding ExcludeFromCoverageAttribute (i.e. consider all code coverable)

Tags: cobertura, dotnet-cli, vstest, coverlet

I am running test using  dotnet test  (dotnet SDK version: 6.0.402)

the command looks like this

```
"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe" test "D:\MyRepo\MyProj.csproj" /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:SolutionDir=D:\MyRepo --configuration Release --logger "trx;logfilename=MyProj.UnitTest.csproj.trx" --no-build --no-restore --results-directory="testOutput"
```

I am **not** providing a .runsettings file at the moment.
Now, I'd like the execution to bypass the behaviour of ExcludeFromCoverageAttribute. In other words, I want cobertura to consider all code coverable, even that annotated with ExcludeFromCoverageAttribute

I've tried passing my own .runsettings file with a datacollector that didn't exclude such attribute, but it doesn't seem to be making a difference

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: is there a reason you want to keep that attribute ?

Comment: @CodingMytra yes, lots of legacy code I don't want to refactor (and can't refactor either)